# How to increase the duration logic in SQL SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure which deletes the records from DB based on following logic.

```
     Select Id into #deleterecords from pricetable where 
     ((Convert(date, modifiedon) <> convert(date,gatedate())
```

I would like to add one more day in     Gatedate()

I’m trying in this

```
       Select Id into #deleterecords from pricetable where 
     ((Convert(date, modifiedon) < > convert(date,gatedate()+1)
```

It’s not working.

How can I add one more day?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "It’s not working."? Are you getting some error message?

Did you mean to write `GETDATE()` (the built-in function that returns the current timestamp), or you indeed have a `gatedate()` function in your database?

To add a day to a `datetime` value in SQL Server use the function [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
select Id 
into #deleterecords 
from pricetable 
where 
    convert(date, modifiedon) <> convert(date, DATEADD(day, 1, gatedate()))
;
```